# How do I incorporate variables in GOAP when planning regressively from the goal?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, planning

I am looking at and reading resources like this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

I have made a forward-searching planner using A*; but am now trying to search backwards for the efficiency gains.

Orkin specifically says

> The planning example illustrated in Figure 2 consists of actions that have constant
>   Boolean values for preconditions and effects, but it is important to point out that
>   preconditions and effects can also represented by variables. The planner solves for these
>   variables as it regresses from the goal. Variables add power and flexibility to the planner,
>   as it can now satisfy more general preconditions. For instance, a Goto action with the
>   effect of moving a character to a variable destination is far more powerful than a Goto
>   action that moves to a constant, predetermined location.

So I'm not attempting to visualise this prior to implementing it; but I cannot work out how to solve the variables moving away from where they're needed:

```
        KEY             CURRENT     GOAL

    itemStockpiled      false       true
    ------------------------------------------

                StockpileItem       Effect:     itemStockpiled true
                                    Precond:    hasItem ?itemId?     **** How can I test this?
                                                agentAtPosition ?stockPos?

    itemStockpiled      true        true
    hasItem             0           ?itemId?
    agentAtPosition     ???         ?stockPos?
    ------------------------------------------

                Goto                Effect:     agentAtPosition ?stockPos?  **** Where is this?

    itemStockpiled      true        true
    hasItem             0           ?itemId?
    agentAtPosition     ?stockPos?  ?stockPos?
    ------------------------------------------

                PickupItem          Effect:     hasItem ?itemId?
                                    Precond:    agentAtPosition ?itemPos?

    itemStockpiled      true        true
    hasItem             ?itemId?    ?itemId?
    agentAtPosition     ?stockPos?  ?itemPos?      **** So we need to go 
                                                   back to the item from
                                                   the stockpile pos
    ------------------------------------------

                Goto                Effect:     agentAtPosition ?itemPos?    **** Where is this?
                                    Precond:    foundItem true

    itemStockpiled      true        true
    hasItem             ?itemId?    ?itemId?
    agentAtPosition     ?itemPos?  ?itemPos?
    foundItem           false       true
    ------------------------------------------

                FindItem            Effect: foundItem true

    itemStockpiled      true        true
    hasItem             ?itemId?    ?itemId?
    agentAtPosition     ?itemPos?  ?itemPos?
    foundItem           true       true
    ------------------------------------------
```

You'll see how in the above comments, I don't understand how I can check for things like an existance of a path, before I know where I'm finding a path too. For the item, I imaging I can have a boolean flag of "hasItem", and keep track of the itemId in a variable that isn't populated until `FindItem` is successful (and then used when executing the path); but how would this work with a `GoTo` action?

If I use a world-state variable "agentAtPosition" as an effect for `Goto`; it will be set at two different points in the plan; meaning that subsequent actions that need "agentAtPosition" to be true will already have their preconditions met, effectively ending the planning, erroneously thinking it found a path:

```
        KEY             CURRENT     GOAL

    itemStockpiled      false       true
    ------------------------------------------

                StockpileItem       Effect:     itemStockpiled true
                                    Precond:    hasItem true
                                                agentAtPosition true

    itemStockpiled      true        true
    hasItem             false       true
    agentAtPosition     false       true
    ------------------------------------------

                Goto                Effect:     agentAtPosition true

    itemStockpiled      true        true
    hasItem             false       true
    agentAtPosition     true        true
    ------------------------------------------

                PickupItem          Effect:     hasItem true
                                    Precond:    agentAtPosition true

    itemStockpiled      true        true
    hasItem             true        true
    agentAtPosition     true        true
    ------------------------------------------
```

How do I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if still relevant, but recently I also implemented the regressive GOAP. I also tried to calculate the movement distance from the future target to the past target (use the travel distance as a heuristic cost as was suggested in the [GDC talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gm7K68663rA)) and realized it becomes too complex as I had a logic where the NPC would pick the nearest cover spot, but then what is the nearest at that point in time?
It was helpful for me to imagine regressive GOAP as travelling back in time - if you change something in the past - it will invalidate the future.
My solution to this was to not use travel distance as a heuristic cost of action and to let the action determine itself what the target is and where to move to when the plan is being executed.
Removing the `GoTo` action will also help to reduce the plan size, which was also suggested by the previously mentioned talk.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. I'm pouring over the FEAR sdk like my jobs on the line.

In [CAIActionUseSmartObjectNode](https://github.com/xfw5/Fear-SDK-1.08/blob/2fc3557b0037d5fe01ac607b907d4b8511b9e4b2/Game/ObjectDLL/AIActionUseSmartObjectNode.cpp#L62), they require as a precondition that the world state of `kWSK_AtNode` is equivalent to the variable `kWSK_UsingObject`, which is the object you intend to use.

```
m_wsWorldStatePreconditions.SetWSProp( kWSK_AtNode, NULL, kWST_Variable, kWSK_UsingObject );
```

So far we don't yet know how `kWSK_UsingObject` is defined, but ostensibly it can be anything and we need to track it, as your question entails.

In [CAIActionGotoNode](https://github.com/xfw5/Fear-SDK-1.08/blob/2fc3557b0037d5fe01ac607b907d4b8511b9e4b2/Game/ObjectDLL/AIActionGotoNode.cpp#L60), it tell us that it will set our needed `kWSK_AtNode` value to idk *some* `kWSK_AtNode` (non nil) value.

```
m_wsWorldStateEffects.SetWSProp( kWSK_AtNode, NULL, kWST_Variable, kWSK_AtNode );
```

This means that it can get us to the node we need to use, but it too is generic with its variables.

In CAIActionGotoNode's [ValidateContextPreconditions function](https://github.com/xfw5/Fear-SDK-1.08/blob/2fc3557b0037d5fe01ac607b907d4b8511b9e4b2/Game/ObjectDLL/AIActionGotoNode.cpp#L82), it get's the goal it needs to be at from `wsWorldStateGoal`:

```
// Find which node we are going to from the goal world state.
SAIWORLDSTATE_PROP* pProp = wsWorldStateGoal.GetWSProp( kWSK_AtNode, pAI->m_hObject );
```

This tells me that at some point we must be writing `kWSK_AtNode` to `wsWorldStateGoal`.

[Here are the places](https://pastebin.com/vYtkbBF7) I found `kWSK_AtNode` and `kWSK_UsingObject` being assigned to by actions. You'll be surprised to find it's like 5 places, and they all seem off hand. There were dozens of places this was assigned in goals not included here.

Could it be that the system *isn't designed* to have multiple goto uses within one path through the actions? Supposedly most action lists have fewer than three actions in FEAR. If so, that really, really lame. But I'm not seeing examples of chaining it together.

I didn't want to XY problem you or XY problem me. Have you considered moving your groups of actions into goals themselves? Finding the item will be one, which item to use is defined in a goal, and picking it up another? That way your goal can assign what item to handle, and there's never two actions overlapping over which thing to go to.

I was surprised by the simplicity of the goals in FEAR. It isn't "SEARCH AND DESTROY BY WHATEVER MEANS" its "ok so ur gonna charge by walking and shooting mkay?".

Answer (score -1):

So, it seems GOPA is this: http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~jorkin/goap.html.
I'd have linked the reference.

I don't understand what's you are trying to do and the paragraph you quote from "Orkin" (that I don't know about). However, this part is only an intuition:

> Variables add power and flexibility to the planner, as it can now satisfy more general preconditions.

One must distinguish between changing the problem and changing the solution. If you implemented an A* forward search algorithm, then implementing full regression is a matter of implementing the regression operation of A over state s: the partial states s' that must have come before s is such that:
- the preconditions of A were true in s'
- the effects of A are consistent with s
- A is relevant for getting from s' to s. If there are no negative preconditions, then there is at least one p in add(A) that is not in s' but is in s.

Now, "adding variables" sounds like reformulating the problem. In that case, the main question is:
- is that reformulation preserving all the paths? 
If not, it should merge some paths in a precise way. Otherwise, it's not a reformulation.

So, the first question is not about forward or backward search, is about confirming what are the possible paths. If the possible paths are correct, then regression should work.

Unless you are actually trying to do something smarter like not bounding objects until necessary.

I suggest 1st focusing on a simpler version where standard regression make sense, and then revisit what you want to do.